# Is this the data construction 'or' Enum type in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

The Code A is from https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/utils/ViewExtensions.kt

Is this the data construction 'or' Enum type ?  is `FLAGS_FULLSCREEN` assigned a value by system configuration? sometimes it's `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` , sometimes it's `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE,` right?

Is the keyword 'or' defined by Kotlin?

**Code A**

```
const val FLAGS_FULLSCREEN =
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
```

Comment: `or` is Kotlin's syntax for `||`

Comment: @AjahnCharles It isn't, see Todd's answer.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing... I was fully aware that this was a bitwise *or*, but I mistakenly thought that Java used `||` for both bitwise *or* (as well as for boolean or), and that Kotlin used `or` (for both). Apparently neither of those is correct! So despite knowing what it meant here, I still managed to post a completely misleading answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `or` syntax in Kotlin is used to do a [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR). Each one of the constants (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE, View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN, etc...) represents an integer value that is a power of two. By or-ing them together we create a single integer value.

For example, suppose we have three constants A (value 1), B (value 2), and C (value 4). If we wanted to create a value that is the combination of A and C, we would or them together.

This is their binary and integer representations:

```
A = 001 (1)
C = 100 (4)
    ---
    101

For the sake of completeness, B would be `010`.
```

And by looking at `0101`, we can tell (by using [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)) which flags were set (A, and C) and which were not (B).

So yes, we *could* view it as a kind of enumeration, but not a java/kotlin enum.

Comment: Thanks!   If we wanted to create a value that is the combination of A and C, the expression should be `const val my=1 or 4`, or it's `const val my=A or C`,  right?